# How to show line (symbol) in text

Tags: symbols, text

In latex how to show different types of line, in symbol form as ---- and other forms, in text line.

[image]

Comment: `\tikz\draw[...] ...;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With TikZ you can define your own dash and dot patterns and embed the picture inline using `\tikz`.  As none of the macros in TikZ is e-TeX protected you have to take care of that by yourself by using `\protected\def` or in this case `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools,tikz,caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc,labelsep=period}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sampleline[1]{%
  \tikz\draw[#1] (0,0) (0,\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax)
  -- (2em,\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax);%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{One-dimensional Fourier spectra for Case A ($M =
    1.5$) at (\emph{a}, \emph{c}) near the wall, $1 - \lvert y \rvert =
    0.04$, and (\emph{b}, \emph{d}) at the centerline:
    \sampleline{}, $\rho$;
    \sampleline{dashed}, $u$;
    \sampleline{dotted}, $v$;
    \sampleline{dash pattern=on .7em off .2em on .2em off .2em}, $w$;
    \sampleline{dash pattern=on .7em off .2em on .05em off .2em}, $T$.
    (\emph{a}, \emph{b}) Streamwise;
    (\emph{c}, \emph{d}) spanwise.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with some `\rule`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\begin{document}

One-dimensional Fourier spectra for Case~A ($M = 1.5$) at $(a,c)$ near the wall,
$1 - |y| = 0.04$, and $(b,d)$ at the centerline:
  \rule[.5ex]{2em}{.4pt},~$p$;
  \makebox[2em]{\xdotfill{.4pt}},~$u$;
  $\cdot\,\cdot\,\cdot\,\cdot\,\cdot$,~$v$;
  \rule[.5ex]{1em}{.4pt}\,\rule[.5ex]{.2em}{.4pt}\,\rule[.5ex]{1em}{.4pt},~$w$;
  \rule[.5ex]{1em}{.4pt}\,$\cdot$\,\rule[.5ex]{1em}{.4pt},~$T$.
$(a,b)$ Streamwise;
$(c,d)$ spanwise.

\end{document}
```

Note that `\leaders` and `\rule`s have problems surviving `\caption`s, so you may be forced to use the optional argument if you want alternative content to migrate successfully to the LoF/LoT.

Comment: I think the line corresponding to `u` should be dashed, rather than loosely dotted.  Also a,b,c, and d are presumably labels for subfigures, i.e. no math variables.